# Why does this code not cause a dead-lock?

Tags: c++, mutex, deadlock

I have below code where function bar lock the mutex and then called function foo, however function foo lock the same mutex. according to my understanding, dead-lock will take place because foo are trying to lock the same mutex and it has been locked in function bar. But below code executes without any halt. Who knows the reason??

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void foo()  
{  
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);  
    cout<<"excuting foo!!"<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);  
}  

void bar()  
{  
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);  
    cout<<"excuting bar!!"<<endl;
    foo();  
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);  
}


int main()
{
    bar();
}
```

Comment: Deadlocks for me. I recommend completing the [mre] in case I accidentally fixed the "bug" while filling in the blanks.

Comment: You're also not checking the return value of pthread_mutex_lock. If your system supports some basic deadlock detection, it might simply be returning an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [POSIX thread specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) allows a POSIX thread implementation to use any of the standard three mutex types as the default one:

> If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT, the behavior of
>   pthread_mutex_lock() may correspond to one of the three other standard
>   mutex types

What is `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT`? That's [pretty much what you expect](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_settype.html):

> The default value of the type attribute is PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT.
>
> ...
>
> An implementation may map PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT to one of the other
>   mutex types.

You are expecting your mutex to be `PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL` which will cause a deadlock here. However, your particular thread implementation appears to be the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` type, which can be locked more than once by the same process. This is the behavior you are observing.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to modify bar() as: 
void bar()  
{  
       pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);  
        cout<<"excuting bar!!"<<endl;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 
        foo();  

}
```

In your code, deadlock is there because sequence is following
 1. bar () locks mutex, 
2. Foo() trying to lock mutex again which is already locked by bar
3. bar() unlocks it,but earlier operation step 2, still waiting for mutex. This steps waits for step 2 to finish

Comment: The question is why this code is _not_ deadlocking for the OP.